# State variables in react-redux store are undefined after console.log?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have made bank account details submit form. When I try to console.log after clicking on submit button I am not able to capture those input values and store it in `redux store`. After using `console.log(this.props)` in constructor and also after using `console.log(this.props.firstname)`, `console.log(this.props.lastname)`, etc. I am getting undefined in console see the screenshot.

Form.js (Form component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as action from '../actions/actions';


import './form.css';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setFirstName = this.setFirstName.bind(this);
    this.setLastName = this.setLastName.bind(this);
    this.setEmailId = this.setEmailId.bind(this);
    this.setIban = this.setIban.bind(this);
     this.setBankName = this.setBankName.bind(this);
    this.showUser = this.showUser.bind(this);

     console.log(this.props);

    }

    setFirstName(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setFirstName(event.target.value));
    }

    setLastName(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setLastName(event.target.value));
    }

    setEmailId(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setEmailId(event.target.value));
    }

    setIban(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setIban(event.target.value));
    }

    setBankName(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setBankName(event.target.value));
    }

    showUser(){
        console.log(this.props.firstname);
        console.log(this.props.lastname);
        console.log(this.props.emailid);
    }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div id="center">
              <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                         <input type="firstname" className="form-control" id="firstname" onChange={this.setFirstName}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                         <input type="lastname" className="form-control" id="lastname" onChange={this.setLastName}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" onChange={this.setEmailId}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label for="bankacc">IBAN:</label>
                         <div id="deletebank" className="items">
                         <input type="bankacc" className="form-control" id="bankacc" onChange={this.setIban}/>
                         <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> 
                         </button>
                         </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label for="bankname">Bank Name:</label>
                         <input type="bankname" className="form-control" id="bankname" onChange={this.setBankName}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <button type="button" className="btn addbank">+ Add bank account</button>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.showUser}>Submit</button>
                    </div>


              </form>
          </div>
      </div>

    )}


}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    firstname: store.firstname,
    lastname: store.lastname,
    emailid: store.emailid,
    iban: store.iban,
    bankname: store.bankname
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Form);
```

actions.js:

```
export const SET_FIRSTNAME = 'SET_FIRSTNAME';
export const SET_LASTNAME = 'SET_LASTNAME';
export const SET_EMAILID = 'SET_EMAILID';
export const SET_IBAN = 'SET_IBAN';
export const SET_BANKNAME = 'SET_BANKNAME';


export function setFirstName(firstname){
    return {
        type:SET_FIRSTNAME,
        payLoad:firstname
    }
}

export function setLastName(lastname){
    return {
        type:SET_LASTNAME,
        payLoad:lastname
    }
}

export function setEmailId(emailid){
    return {
        type:SET_EMAILID,
        payLoad:emailid
    }
}

export function setIban(iban){
    return {
        type:SET_IBAN,
        payLoad:iban
    }
}

export function setBankName(bankname){
    return {
        type:SET_BANKNAME,
        payLoad:bankname
    }
}
```

Reducer.js:

```
const userReducer = (state = {
  user:{
    firstname:'',
    lastname:'',
    emailid:'',
    bankaccounts:{
      iban:'',
      bankname:''
    }
  }
  }, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_FIRSTNAME':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, firstname: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_LASTNAME':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, lastname: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_EMAILID':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, emailid: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_IBAN':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, iban: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_BANKNAME':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, bankname: action.payload}
      }
    }
    default: return state;
  }

}

export default userReducer;
```

screenshot:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: seems like you are calling the function instead of passing it as a reference: try to change this line `onClick={this.showUser()}` to this `onClick={this.showUser}`

Comment: @Sagivb.g I have made those changes but still does not work.

Comment: @Sagivb.g I think I am doing something wrong in reducers but could not figure it out.

Comment: there is another issue in `mapStateToProps`, i've posted an answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root reducer which is `UserReducer` is an object with a property `user`.
In `mapStateToProps` you should access it like this `store.user.lastname` instead of `store.lastname`

```
const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    firstname: store.user.firstname,
    lastname: store.user.lastname,
    emailid: store.user.emailid,
    iban: store.user.iban,
    bankname: store.user.bankname
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks. One question, should use `iban: store.user.bankaccount.iban,` instead of `iban: store.user.iban`, Similarly for bankname.

Comment: I am not able to display `iban` and `bankname` in console I tried `console.log(this.props.iban)` but it display blank space. See the screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/402Jn5a . On left side of console it shows blank space but on right side it shows the input value in console why so ?

Comment: You should edit your answer because `iban: store.user.bankaccounts.iban` and `bankname: store.user.bankaccounts.bankname` does not work.It should be changed to `bankname: store.user.bankname` and `iban: store.user.iban`. If I make these changes then I don't face any errors Check my previous comment for error which I was getting.

Comment: This means that your initial state is not the same as well.

Comment: I did not get you ? Initial state ? Yes the initial state is empty string for all variables.

Comment: But you got `user.bankacounts.iban` there, so i guess this needs to be changed as well

Comment: Ok so if I need to change `iban` or `bankname`. I have to use ` iban: store.user.iban` and `bankname: store.user.bankname` is it correct ?

Comment: All im saying is that your initial state object shape should be the same as your reducer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this into constructor:

```
this.showUser = this.showUser.bind(this);
```

Comment: I have done that but now when I submit I am getting 3 `undefined` values in console.